# How do I show the product SKU instead of it's name in the breadcrumb trail in Magento?

Tags: magento, product, breadcrumbs, skus

I'm trying to show the product SKU in the breadcrumb trail instead of the product name. Does anyone have any ideas as how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: hmm by replacing the name variable getName()  to getSku() ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just tried that now in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Data.php (in the getBreadcrumbPath function. It works, but it also changes the page title. Any idea of a way around that?

Comment: change it in template not in helper

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I should go about doing that? The breadcrumbs template file is generic for all pages which, for the product anyway, is set in that controller. I'm sure it's obvious and I'm just not thinking right. Thanks!

Comment: implement your own template if it is too general or add conditions to existing one. seems like you are not thinking at all :D

Comment: Essentially you've done the right thing.  However I'd recommend rewriting the helper rather than editing the core files.  I'll submit and answer with instructions.

Comment: Adam, yeah, I should have elaborated, I was just using the core files to see if i was in the right place. A answer with instructions would be very much appreciated though!

Answer (score 0):

you could use a plugin to change this

Magento sets the product name for breadcrumb here
Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs

```
public function getJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped() : string
    {
        return json_encode(
            [
                'breadcrumbs' => [
                    'categoryUrlSuffix' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->getCategoryUrlSuffix()),
                    'useCategoryPathInUrl' => (int)$this->isCategoryUsedInProductUrl(),
                    'product' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->getProductName())
                ]
            ],
            JSON_HEX_TAG
        );
    }
```

You can add a plugin to your custom module.
In your plugin add a function to get the product sku
then add the function afterGetJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped to update getJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped to use the sku instead of the name.

afterGetJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped($subject)

```
 /**
 * Returns product sku.
 *
 * @return string
 * Add this function to get your Sku
 */
public function getProductSku(): string
{
    return $this->catalogData->getProduct() !== null
        ? $this->catalogData->getProduct()->getSku()
        : '';
}

/**
 * Returns breadcrumb json with html escaped Sku
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function afterGetJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped($subject) : string
{
    return json_encode(
        [
            'breadcrumbs' => [
                'categoryUrlSuffix' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($subject->getCategoryUrlSuffix()),
                'useCategoryPathInUrl' => (int)$subject->isCategoryUsedInProductUrl(),
                'product' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->getProductSku())
            ]
        ],
        JSON_HEX_TAG
    );
}
```